# Fix a mishapen curved edge so that it is uniform

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

I created a curvy shape that ended up with really ugly geometry. When I tried cleaning it up, I ended up warping the curve in places and now I am really unclear on how I can fix it. I thought about chopping it in half and then mirroring it but there are no good halves to mirror. I also tried selecting edge rings and "set flow" but it left me with the situation you can see in the attached pictures. I am really out of ideas and could use whatever helpful ideas anyone one might. This is ultimately for a 3D print job.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is just a cylindrical shape I think the quickest thing to do would be to just select one of the vertical edge loops, separate it, and remake the whole thing with a screw modifier or the spin tool

Comment: yes agreed. very easy fix by selecting 1 vertical edge loop then use this technique https://youtube.com/shorts/IqhQCVTRHJw?si=ympSo6JDNzQlgNBP